# Backquote (<) and ² inverted on my external keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I don't know why, but the ² and < are inverted on my external keyboard.

The ² is right after the left shift, where it's written "<", and the < is at the top of the tab key, where it's written "²" ...

Any idea why, and how I can fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: No such problem with your internal keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same problem on an external Italian Keyboard, as said in the comments by Tom Gewecke the problem was Karabiner.

I want to maintain Karabiner for one of the two keyboards so I've done a "simple modification":

[image]

You can do the same with your inverted keys.

Another solution of the problem is disable Karabiner for a specific Keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I noticed these keys are swapped on my (Belgian) AZERTY keyboard when the keyboard type is set to *ANSI (United States and others)* instead of *ISO (European)*. You can change this setting by going to the *Keyboard* tab of the *Keyboard* preferences and clicking *Change Keyboard Type...*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should give use more information about your external keyboard mapping. Your are only talking about 2 specific keys. That special keys can have different location with respect to your keyboard layout (and brand).

I would say that you have an AZERTY based mapping but where ² and < are inverted : 
[image: AZERTY MAPPING]

**Solution on macOS 10.12**

The best way is:

- go in System preferences > keyboard.
- click Input Sources tab (4th tab on macOS if you're OS is not in English).
- then click on the "**+**" button at the bottom left of the window for adding a new layout.
- browse the AZERTY mapping and try to find which one corresponds to yours.
- tick "**Show input in the menu bar**" (bottom of the window, first option), it let you see you current mapping in your OS menu bar. You should see appear here a country flag or "ABC" or "ABC - AZERTY" or something else depending of your chosen layouts.
  [image]
  [image]

If your external keyboard has an unusual mapping, you have to try manually several kinds of layouts (ex: french/canadian french/swiss french).

- Select the new added layout in the menu bar,
- open a text editor to try if your software mapping corresponds to your physical mapping.
- You should find the good one easily after few attempts.

**If you can't find it**

1. A straightforward solution (if physical keys are similar) is to swap them physically.
2. There is a way to write your own mapping configuration file on an Unix system, but we can talk about that only if nothing goes right.

**Trick**

An easy way for switching your layout whether you are using your laptop or ext. keyboard is to add a shortcut for making the switch:

- go in System preferences > keyboard.
- click "**Shortcuts**" tab (3rd tab).
- select "**Input Sources**" in the left panel.
- then add your special shortcut. 
  [image]

Comment: Wow, That's a complete answer! I already mapped my keyboard to a specific AZERTY layout (sorry I forgot to mention it was azerty). All the keys are working correctly (including ! for example). Moreover, the ">" key, is at the right place (it's shift + <). So "<" and ">" should be on the same key, with "shift" to get ">" but oddly, on my layout, "<" and ">" are located on different key, but not on my keyboard. Is it clear?

Comment: I know it's not clear, so I'll try another explanation : Based on the image of the keyboard layout from your answer, the ² is swapped with < but > is at the correct place. Is it clearer? :)

Comment: Also, the first time I plugged the keyboard, Mac OS asked me to tell what was the key near left shift, so I entered <, but maybe I misread or maybe there was an error, and that caused the layout issue. If I could make Mac OS forget about the initial question, maybe my issue would be fixed?

Comment: @CyrilN.  Do you by chance have Karabiner Elements installed?

Comment: @TomGewecke I did, but I installed after this issue, so it's not related :)

Comment: Your third comment should be the explanation. You could have CAPS ON while typing on the left shift nearest key... I'm busy to night. I will poke around your question about "forgetting this device layout".

Comment: Try first to delete this file: /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist

Comment: Then, reconnect your external keyboard and see what happen

Comment: @CyrilN. Is that working?